# highlight changes between different versions of HTML snippets

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

I need to track changes between different versions of html snippets, the ideal solution would add css classes to changes like the following example (the example is simple, but complex changes should works too).

version 1

```
<ul id="items">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

version 2

```
<ul id="items">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

the result expected, the changes between version 1 and 2

```
<ul id="items">
  <li>one</li>
  <li class="removed">two</li>
  <li class="added">four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not well enough defined. What should happen if there are nested changes? If you're assuming only simple changes, then it shouldn't be difficult to customise any of the diff implementations floating around the interweb.

Comment: it should highlight every changes between two snippets, the example is simple, but complex changes should works too

Comment: What exactly have Ruby to do with this?

Comment: I need to find a ruby solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- UPDATE 29 april 2013

[Google Diff Match PATCH](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) is awesome to compare two blocks of plain text, could be usefull too

-- UPDATE 22 July 2013

same library as above available in seven different ports C++ C# Dart Java Javascript Lua Objectives C and Python

https://github.com/rdt1/hardcore

[htmldiff](https://github.com/myobie/htmldiff) will do the job

other references can be found at

- [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/htmldiff/0.0.1/frames)
- [the ruby gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/htmldiff)